# Actions on Google: Beta Release Denied

Tags: actions-on-google

I have deployed my app in Beta release, but AoG review team denied it and identify these two issues:

1. During our review we found out that the OAuth URL is not belong to the owner of the app. Please make sure the OAuth URL is owned by the internal party.
2. Your provided testing instructions either did not work correctly or were not substantial enough. Please ensure that you are providing everything needed for us to test your app, and that all credentials you provide work correctly.

For Issue#1:
For Account Linking, I am using "OAuth and Google Sign In" and "Authorization code" as a Linking Type and it works fine and successfully provide Access Token.
below is the attachment of the snapshot of the "client Information"
[image]

For Issue#2:
What credentials they need for testing, because I simply authenticate the user from Google by their Gmail account, it works fine for both Draft and Alpha version.

Please help me to resolve these issues.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using any of the Account Linking types that include "OAuth", then you are expected to provide an OAuth server that is under your control. By definition, Google Accounts are not under your control. The Authorization and Token URLs that you provide should be the server that you control.

If you do not have another OAuth server, then you should be able to just be able to use the "Google Sign In" method, which will not require you to add the Auth or Token URLs or require additional credentials.

Comment: I am using action on google Nodejs client library v1, do you have any sample code of Google sign In for v1 library?

Comment: That sounds like a separate question, and I suggest you post it as a new StackOverflow question, and be clear on exactly which library and which version you're talking about (post your package.json, for example).